# Polylang will not allow changing of language without translation

Tags: customization, template-redirect, plugin-polylang

I am using polylang plugin to translate a website which uses custom theme. 
We are using custom post type. We want to use custom translation for that post type. We will not use polylang to translate custom post type posts.

So, the issue is it will not allow us to change the language for that post type since we are not using polylang for that. I want to force the change of language despite no translation available.

Let me know if anyone has solution for same :)

Comment: How are you configuring WordPress to find the right translation for that post if you're not using Polylang for it? Why do you need to set the language / what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: But I don't know the Polylang plugin very well. You might do better asking their support for help.

Comment: I have a post type for auctions.. User will not add auction in all languages. So I am using only english version for that post type.

Comment: But I still want to change the language on auction pages. So that I can translate strings using loco translate for auctions along with the data entered by user.